# Why use monorepo instead of deployment management project

Tags: deployment, monorepo

Why use A to manage a project instead of dividing it into multiple projects and managing them during deployment?

What are the benefits of using a single project（mono repo） to manage projects, and splitting multiple projects and deploying them in different paths? A single project is more complicated in branch management

Is it because of the encapsulation of public modules?